# Add files of one type to one zip file and clean up using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, zip

How can I create a PowerShell script to get all files of type .BAK and add them to a ZIP file (can I have my PowerShell script take a parameter when called to control the name of the ZIP file that will house all the .bak files? Deleting the .bak files once successfully zipped up.

The current directory is:

```
C:\SQLBackups
+- a.bak
+- b.bak
`- c.bak
```

Goal is:

```
C:\SQLBackups
`- v4.14.4_backups.zip
```

I'm pretty new to PowerShell, and I have currently the script zipping every .bak file into a .zip file which is no good.

```cs
$filePath = "C:\SQLBackups\"
$bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath |
       Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".bak" }

if (-not (Test-Path "$env:C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {
  throw "$env:Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"
}
Set-Alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

foreach ($file in $bak) {
  $name = $file.Name
  $directory = $file.DirectoryName
  $zipfile = $name.Replace(".bak", ".zip")
  sz a -t7z "$directory\$zipfile" "$directory\$name"
}
```

The current output would be:

```
a.bak
a.zip
b.bak
b.zip
c.bak
c.zip
```

Comment: Please clarify _by directly updating your question_ whether you want just 1 ZIP file for all `*.bak` files in the _entire subtree_ of `C:\SQLBackups` - given that you're using `-Recurse` - or whether you want 1 ZIP file _per directory_ in that subtree.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PowerShell v5 then you can use the `Compress-Archive` function instead of using 7zip:

```
$filePath = "C:\SQLBackups"
$ZipName = "v4.14.4_backups.zip"

$BakFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath -Include *.bak

$BakFiles | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$filePath\$ZipName"
$BakFiles | Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You name the archive after each file you're processing in the loop, hence each file goes into its own archive. If you want to put all files into the same archive, define the archive name once outside the loop:

```
$zipfile = Join-Path $filePath 'v4.14.4_backups.zip'
foreach ($file in $bak) {
  sz a -t7z $zipfile $file.FullName
}
```